# is there a way to control the FLVPlayback component's volume using the slider component in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, slider, flash-cs5, audio, flvplayback

I was wondering if there was a way to get the sound from a FLVPlayback component and manipulate it with using a custom volume slider?

Within my Actionscript I currently have this code which enables me to control the volume of a MP3:

```
import fl.events.SliderEvent;

var mysong = new music();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var myTransform = new SoundTransform();
myChannel = mysong.play(0,10); 

slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, changeVolume);
function changeVolume(event:SliderEvent):void{
myTransform.volume=slider.value;
myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
}
```

But Instead of using the MP3 for sound, is there a way to use an FLV's sound instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this example](http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/12/22/setting-the-volume-on-an-flvplayback-component-in-flash-using-actionscript-30/).  It shows how to do what you are asking.

Basically you need to create the `FLVPlayback` component either using the following code or just within the flash visual layout editor.

```
var flvPlayback:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
```

Once you have your player you can just use its volume property inside of an event listener like the following:

```
function slider_change(evt:SliderEvent):void {
    flvPlayback.volume = evt.value;
}
```

Set your slider component to trigger that event listener function and you should be good to go.

So basically it looks to me like the key part you are missing is that the `FLVPlayback` objects have an actual `voume` property that you can set.  Do it the same way you have your mp3 player set up but change the volume property of the actual `FLVPlayback` object.